# Excel crashing when delete a combo box in excel and trying to save the workbook using VSTO addin

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-addins

I created a VSTO addin which will perform the following actions

Step 1. In addin startup I'm creating a combo box in an excel cell.

Step 2. Added a delete button in ribbon control and on click of button delete the combo box added in step 1.

Step 3. Add a button for save and Save the workbook on click.

On click of save excel is getting crashed and restart excel. Any help will  be appreciated?

Here I'm attaching the code snippet.

public partial class ThisAddIn

```
{

    static Excel.Worksheet Sheet;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)

    {

        Sheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;

        var oleObject = CreateComboBox();

    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)

    {

    }

    /// <summary>

    /// Delete the page filter added

    /// </summary>

    public static void DeletePageFilters()

    {

        for (int i = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count; i > 0; i--)

        {

            Excel.Shape oleObj = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Shapes.Item(i);

            if (oleObj.Name.Contains("Combo"))

            {

                try

                {

                    oleObj.Delete();

                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oleObj);

                }

                catch (Exception ex) { }

            }

        }

    }

    /// <summary>

    /// Create the page filter 

    /// </summary>

    public static Excel.Shape CreateComboBox()

    {

        Excel.Shape oCombo = null;

        try

        {

            Excel.Range cell = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range["A1", "A1"];

            oCombo = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddOLEObject("Forms.ComboBox.1", Type.Missing, Type.Missing,

                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,

                cell.Left, cell.Top, 40, cell.Height);

        }

        catch (System.Exception ex)

        {

        }

        return oCombo;

    }
```

Code to save the workbook
private void Save_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)

```
    {

        try

        {

            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save();

        }

        catch (Exception)

        {

            throw;

        }

    }
```

Event Log

Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 16.0.13127.21624, time stamp: 0x6093b3ca

Faulting module name: VBE7.DLL, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5ff762b0

Exception code: 0xc0000005

Fault offset: 0x0000000000250081

Faulting process id: 0x69c4

Faulting application start time: 0x01d76368d4ad66cc

Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE

Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA7.1\VBE7.DLL

Report Id: 99cb77c6-5e34-4472-a469-3295d1136167

Faulting package full name:

Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue with a new workbook? I've noticed that a single combo box is added but removed all existing controls.

Comment: How can you call Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook in the Addin startup? This code should be in the WorkbookOpen event.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Yes. I'm trying to reproduce the issue in new workbook. I have added only one control - combobox. Nothing else. That's why I removed all controls. Even if I'm deleting only combobox and then save workbook excel is crashing. So i think the issue is with delete and save.